# Take an array of any value type as formal parameter

Tags: c#, declaration, value-type

I would like to be able to declare a function as

```
void foo(<any value type>[] data){}
```

in C# 2.0.  If I declare it as

```
void foo(ValueType[] data){}
```

it compiles, but then the elements in data[] are treated as though they're derived from `object`, e.g. I can't say something like

```
fixed (void* pData = data){}
```

I'd like to avoid taking the void* as the parameter -- I just want to be able to accept any value-type array and then do unmanaged things to it.

ETA: Also, this has the same problem:

```
public static unsafe void foo<T>(T[] data) where T:struct{
  fixed(void *p = data){}
}
```

in case you were wondering.  Fixed fails because it's treated as a managed type -- CS0208, cannot declare a pointer to a managed type.  See "mm" below.  I think he's right... it probably just can't be done.

Comment: LOL - 'do unmanaged things to it' - it sounds quite obscene ;-)

Comment: Indeed! +1 just for that... reminds me of "do unimaginable things to it"

Comment: yes! that's the word I was looking for - 'unimaginable'... thank you

Comment: That last generics-based solution you had should work in any case. Can you provide the code that shows what exactly you're seeing fail with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using C#. Structs do not inherit (however loosely) from System.ValueType until after compile time so you can't match Foo's method signature via polymorphism. Generics are also out according to the language specification:

> "An unmanaged-type is any type that isn’t a reference-type, a **type-parameter**, or a generic struct-type and
>   contains no fields whose type is not an unmanaged-type."

So that's why you can't take the address of T[] regardless of the struct constraint.

You could declare a struct type (say, Bar) as the argument to Foo, compile the code, and change the method signature at the IL level:

`.method private hidebysig static void  Foo(valuetype [mscorlib]System.ValueType[] args) cil managed`

And then the call as well:

`IL_0020:  call       void ConsoleApplication1.Program::Foo(valuetype [mscorlib]System.ValueType[])`

While I was able to run the resulting program I don't know what kind of side effects this has. Also, even if you could reference the modified function you wouldn't be able to call it from C# because again structs don't inherit from System.ValueType until after compilation so the method signature wouldn't match.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void foo<T>(params T[] args) where T : struct {
}
public void SomeMethod() {
    foo(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

You shouldn't have to enter the generic parameter because the compiler will pick up on the type from the first parameter of foo.

Answer (score -1):

This would work:

```
    public static void foo(System.Array data)
    {

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foo(new int[10]);  
    }
```

It doesn't enforce that the array is an array of value types, but it would work.